# MongoDB design advice needed

Tags: php, mongodb, schema

I got an API build with PHP and MySQL. I want to migrate the database to MongoDB but need some advice about the design.

The API contains users and friends. I got one table for the users and one for the friends (connections).

**Users**

```
- id
- firstname
- lastname
- email
- password
```

**Friends**

```
- id
- user_id
- friend_id
```

I am thinking of using this design in MongoDB, is that a good way even if the user got 1000 friends?

**Users**

```
- id
- firstname
- lastname
- email
- password
-- Friends
--- ID of friend #1
--- ID of friend #2
--- ID of friend #3
```

Can I use the friend ID to get the friends entire document then? Is this good?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes; This would be the right way to go.  This book explains a little bit more of that exact method:

[Free Mongo DB Book](http://openmymind.net/mongodb.pdf)

The author talks about not having joins and using a Manager / Employee relationship.  In the case you have.

Quite an outstanding read which may answer other questions you have as well.

Here's the specific snippet which I'm referring to:

> Arrays and Embedded Documents
>   Just because MongoDB doesn't have joins doesn't mean it doesn't have a few tricks up its
>   sleeve. Remember when we quickly saw that MongoDB supports arrays as first class objects
>   of a document? It turns out that this is incredibly handy when dealing with many-to-one or
>   many-to-many relationships. As a simple example, if an employee could have two managers,
>   we could simply store these in an array:

```
db.employees.insert({_id: ObjectId("4d85c7039ab0fd70a117d733"), name: 'Siona',
manager: [ObjectId("4d85c7039ab0fd70a117d730"), ObjectId("4
d85c7039ab0fd70a117d732")] }
```

> Of particular interest is that, for some documents, manager can be a scalar value, while for
>   others it can be an array.

Best of luck!

Comment: Another thing. How many "friend objects" can this document hold before it gets to big to handle. Is 200 to big?

Comment: You could use this design, given that the application will need to validate the relationship e.g. When a user is deleted, it has to be removed from Friends list of all users who contain a reference.